# How does velocity vary with DISTANCE travelled (in a straight line motion) if $a<0$, $a=0$ and $a>0$?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, kinematics, acceleration, velocity

NB: This is about velocity against distance **not** against time and $a$=acceleration

I know for a fact that for $a<0$, the gradient is negative and keeps decreasing, $a=0$ gradient 0. What happens when $a>0$ and can you explain this in terms of equations or any method for when $a<0$ and $a>0$ why it produce this result. I tried using $v^2 = u^2 + 2as$ but it gets confusing for me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you dealing with constant acceleration then $v^2=u^2+2as$ can be written as $v^2=2a\cdot s + u^2$ which is of the form of the general equation of a straight line $y=mx+c$ where if $v^2$ is plotted against $s$ the gradient is $2a$ and the intercept on the $v^2$ axis is $u^2$.

Comment: Oh Ic thats quite helpful. I was having trouble doing it without demos thats why its hard for me to visualize. Now that I know that the answer is so simple I want to punch myself. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

The relationship between a, v (velocity), and d (distance travelled) is in time; you travel a distance d = d(t), where t is the amount of time it takes you to travel that distance.

In other words, how much the velocity varies with distance is a function of how it would vary over that time.

The equation $v^2 = u^2 + 2as$ takes advantage of the relationship between distance and time to relate $a$, $v$, and $d$ (in this equation $s$) directly. It says that if you start at velocity = $u$ and move a distance of $s$ with an acceleration of $a$ you will end up at a velocity $v$. Set $u$ equal to zero (we can do this if we are assuming there are no velocity dependent forces acting on the object). The equation is now $v^2 = 2as$, which is equivalent to $$v = \sqrt{2as}$$

That is a direct relationship expressing how velocity varies over distance given an a. When a > 0, velocity will increase.

When a = 0, velocity will not change. When a < 0, velocity will increase in the opposite direction - i.e., decrease in the "positive" direction. (*Note, since we can not take the sqrt of a negative number, we can simply switch which way we consider the positive direction, get the resultant velocity, and 'map it back' to the original positive direction by slapping a negative on it.*)

This is just one way to think of it. I am sure there are more mathematically satisfying answers than changing coordinate systems to deal with negative acceleration, but the result will be the same.